# How to select only the first level children in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure in my DOM and I would like to select only the first level children from a specified class. How to do this in JQuery?

Please note that I have nested divs with same css class.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="t">
    <div>title</div>
    <div class="ch">
        <input type="text name="input1" value="" id="i1">
    </div>
    <div class="t">
        <div>sub title</div>
        <div class="ch">
            <input type="text name="input2" value="" id="i2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What I need to get:**
When I find all elements with class 't' and iterate, I want to get the children with class 'ch' that are under (not the ones in the inner div with class 't').

**Javascript**

```
$(".t").each(function() {
    //Get the elements in '.ch' for $(this) and process.
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: first level children only. not all children. For ex: if you take the first div with class "t", I want only the elements from first "ch".

Comment: First level means not nested under other sub elements. Do you mean that, or only the first one that appears?

Comment: You really need to stop, figure out what you need, and update your question to clearly explain it. I can't tell if the nested `.t` elements should be included when getting the `.ch` elements or not.

Comment: If by first level you mean direct sub nodes of a node then children **is** first level. The second `ch`is **not** a child of the outer `t`. If so then please don't use 'first level' as it causes a lot of confusion.

Comment: @M99 is that what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/c68xR/2/ Select every `.t` and top lvl `.ch`?

Comment: @M99: Wait, so now you want every `.t`, but only the `.ch` children of the outermost `.t`?

Comment: ...you know, if you're having that hard of a time expressing which nodes should be selected, you could use some HTML comments to annotate the ones you're targeting.

Comment: I want to iterate through each div with class 't', pick up its direct children 'ch' and put them in a json object. My final json should have the same hierarchy as the DIVS. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where JSON comes in to all this. Are you saying you're creating a JSON structure (a string) comprised of some of the properties of the `.ch` elements?

Comment: @Crazy Train - Yes. As soon as I posted the question, with all good intentions, people bombarded this post with lot of answers with out understanding my question. They didn't give me time to clarify or edit my question. Thanks for your help. But I think we should close this as not a properly formatted/worded question. Shame on my part.

Comment: @M99, if there's a complete lack of understanding, I'd recommend ignoring the answers completely, and focusing on editing the question for clarity. Once you think the question is clearer (examples with expected results help a lot), then just leave a comment on each answer that's still there asking them to re-look at the updated question. That way you're not run ragged trying to respond to each answer, and you can concentrate on fixing the misunderstanding once and for all in the question.

Comment: @M99: Yeah, the as much clarity as possible should be present before you post. You can flag your question for a moderator to delete it if you want. Whether you do that or simply edit it, you should show a representation of the JSON data you're hoping to build, and clearly indicate which elements should be used to build it.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `children` selector

Something like

```
$('.t').children('.ch')
```

This is equivalent to

```
$('.t > .ch') // Child selector
```

And you can remove the `each` loop from the code as the selector selects the elements you are looking for.

**Edit**

For First level you can use a combination of `child selector` and `parents` method

```
$('.t > .ch').filter(function() {
   return $(this).parents('.t').length === 1 
})
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fsz3P/)**

Comment: Can you elaborate on why using the `children()` method would be better? `.t > .ch` is definitely not deprecated, and is a valid CSS selector that can be fed to `querySelectorAll()`, which is usually faster.

Comment: This doesn't actually use each the way the OP specified

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi.. I thought i read it somewhere and you are right.. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Sushanth-- I confirm that child selector is faster : http://jsperf.com/child-selector-vs-children23

Comment: I only want first level children. not all children. For ex: if you take the first div with class "t", I want only the elements from first "ch".

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It will match both the outer and inner elements. The OP stated to only match the outer elements.

Comment: @Sushaanth it works for level one. I guess its my fault that I didn't word the question properly. What I want to do is: Read each div with class 't' and create JSON with the elements under that as a hierarchy (more like a tree). Nesting you see in Divs would be in JSON also. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the top level `.t`, you can use this :

```
$('.t').not('.t > .t').children('.ch')
```

Then once you got every `.ch` you need, you can iterate through them.

If you want to iterate through the `.t`, then you can get the children inside the loop :

```
$('.t').not('.t > .t').each(function(){
    var ch = $(this).children('.ch')
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c68xR/

---

If you want to select every `.t` and every `.ch` of the first lvl `.t`, that's what you want :

```
$('.t').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('border', 'red 1px solid');
    if(!$this.is('.t > .t')){
        $this.children('.ch').css('border', 'blue 1px solid');
    }
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c68xR/2/

Comment: Looks like you understood the questioner's goal better than the rest of us. Good job :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, gotta admit, it was hard :) Thank!

Answer (score 1):

Playing guessing games here, but is this what you're looking for?

```
$(".t").each(function(i) {
   var childrenCHOnly = $(this).children('.ch');
   /* Do work to childrenCHOnly */
});
```

## jsFiddle

---

Or this:

```
 $(".t").filter(function(i) { return $(this).find('.t').length; }).children('.ch').first();
```

It will filter to only get Elements of `.t` that have inner elements of `.t` and then get the first child `.ch`

## jsFiddle

---

Of course you could also say:

```
$(".t").first().children(".ch").first().each(function(i) { ...
```

|OR|

```
$(".t > .ch").first().each(function(i) { ...
```

Of course, both of these would only grab the very first `.t`, regardless if it was a parent to more or not

Comment: +1 But I think OP wants the top level `.t`, which doesn't necessarily imply that there are nested `.t` elements. The question isn't perfectly clear on that. It may be safer to do `$(this).closest(".t").length === 0` in order to exclude ones that have a `.t` ancestor.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Too true, that's why i've been making some updates, tho it's really hard to tell exactly what s/he wants?

Comment: Agreed. If it can be guaranteed that there will always be nesting, then your first solution would work perfectly.

Comment: I want to read each div with class 't' and create JSON with the elements under that as a hierarchy (more like a tree). Nesting you see in Divs would be in JSON also. Thanks.

Comment: @M99 ok, did you see my latest update, I added one new example, perhaps that would fit?

Comment: I think that will work, I am trying it out. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".t").children(".ch").each(function() {
  // do stuff here
});
```

If you want to target the elements inside of `.ch` element, you can do something like this:

```
$(".t").children(".ch").children().each(function() {
  // do stuff here
});
```

Comment: This isn't actually the way the OP is using each

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you really want to loop through each `.t` element, and find the children of *each one* independently - which the other answers seem to have missed - I think this is what you want:

```
$(".t").each(function() {
    var childen = $(this).children('.ch');
});
```

For the sample HTML given in the original question, we'll loop through the `each` 2 times - once for each `.t` element. The first time through, only the first `.ch` element will be selected, and the second time through, only the second `.ch` element will be selected.

`children()` is different from `find()` in that it only finds immediate (first-level) children of the element it's called on - in this case, `$(this)`, which is the `.t` that was found in the current pass through the loop.

Comment: You understood the question correctly, but $(this).children('.ch') will give all children (even the ones under the nested divs with clss 't').

Comment: @M99: Which is it... he understood the question correctly, or you don't want the `.ch` elements in the nested `.t` elements?

Comment: @m99 No, `children()` only gets immediate children. So when the `each` is at the first `.t`, it'll only get the first `.ch`. When the `each` gets to the second `.t` though, it will get the second `.ch`, because it's a first-level child of that `.t`.

Comment: Well, I'm giving to +1 this and every other answer here. If someone posted a Fibonacci function written in Clojure, I'd probably upvote that one too.