# how to addClass to closest element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a dropdown menu and I want to verify if the submenu hasClass `in`, then for the closest `ul` that has class `.menu` add class `in`. Here is my code but it adds for all `ul` that has class `.menu` instead closest.

```
<script>
  if($(".submenu").hasClass( "in" )) {
    $(".submenu").closest(".menu").addClass("in");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML as well

Comment: can you share html as well

Comment: `closest` finds the closest parent. Edit: oops, I misread!

Comment: @FrankModica `.closest()` searches up the DOM through all ancestors of a given element, not just the parent

Comment: @j08691 and the element itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the selector

```
$(".submenu.in").closest(".menu").addClass("in");
```

---

Alternatively [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) can also be used as

> Selects elements that contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

```
$(".menu:has(.submenu.in)").addClass("in");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

For looking up the DOM use this:

```
<script>
    $('.submenu.in').closest('.menu').addClass("in");
</script>
```

For looking into the children elements use this:

```
<script>
    $('.submenu.in .menu').first().addClass("in");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to target a child element of `.submenu` so try this

```
<script>
  if($(".submenu").hasClass( "in" )) {
    $(".submenu").children(".menu").addClass("in");
  }
</script>
```

Or if you just want first level children here's a solution: [How to select only the first level children in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370465/how-to-select-only-the-first-level-children-in-jquery)